# Order multiple tables in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have this
`ads`

```
ad_id   ad_path     ad_explain      date    
1       1.jpg       something       2012 03:35:10 PM
2       2.jpg       something       2012 03:05:27 PM
```

`books`

```
book_id       book_name     date
1             first         2012 03:45:27 PM
2             second        2012 03:10:27 PM
```

and i want the get all the data from these two tables and order them by date like :

```
book_id       book_name     ad_id    ad_path      ad_explain      date
                             2        2.jpg       something       2012 03:05:27 PM
2             second                                              2012 03:10:27 PM
                             1        1.jpg       something       2012 03:35:10 PM
1             first                                               2012 03:45:27 PM
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of teh Destination Table. Are you expecting each row in the three source tables to result is a seperate row in the destination or do you want to combine data from all three sources in a destination row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want SQL Joins, but you need columns in common to join on.

books and request_books could be joined on book_id, but ads doesn't seem to have a common column with anything (except date, but that seems an unlikely target), so you'd not be able to bring that in easily.

What is your purpose in wanting all three tables mixed together, when it seems like ads doesn't fit the group?

Comment: You are assuming that the OP needs JOINS, when he/she may want UNIONS. The question needs to be clarified before an answer is given.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with UNION:

```
SELECT book_id, book_name, null as ad_id, null as ad_path, null as ad_explain, date
FROM books
UNION
SELECT null, null, ad_id, ad_path, ad_explain, date
FROM ads
ORDER BY date
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29563/23) for working example

Comment: You need to add `order by coalesce(ad_id,book_id) desc , date`  to get the ordering right

Comment: I can see i missed the order by date, but why the coalesce?

Comment: I made an assumption that the op wanted to interleave the book and ad records and not rely solely on date. By I could be really wrong on that

Comment: @Shnage. Did you end up using joins instead? Is that why you accepted the other answer? I thought you found help in my answer and you accepted another that is quite different from my approach.